# Unable to full screen activity when i use onAttachedToWindow

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, android-notification-bar, android-windowmanager

I am trying to override home key and full screen the acitiy using  below code. locking of home key is working fine but it unable to hide notification bar  (unable to full screen the activity).

```
public class ScreenLockDemo extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screenlock);

    }



@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
  this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();  

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        return true;
    }
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.antivirus.antitheft.ScreenLockDemo"
         android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
       >              
    </activity>
```

![out put of above code it cute the topside of layout as show in img. ][1]

i am also trying to setType using handler it full screen the activity but it could not override menu key. please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369144/activity-doesnt-show-in-full-screen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code before setContentView(xml)

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Hope, this will work for you.

Comment: i am trying this code but Not working it cut topside to layout... the above code is not work when i use 

public void onAttachedToWindow()
 {  
   this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
  super.onAttachedToWindow();  

 }
 this method in my code to override the menu key.

Comment: Had you tried this code, you would have discovered that it doesn't work. You don't get the full screen.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to set the activity as full screen is to set it in the manifest. As an example add the following to your activity section within the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Therefore it should look something like:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".blahActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: i already use this code but its not work in the case of  public void onAttachedToWindow()
 {  
   this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
  super.onAttachedToWindow();  

 } this method

Answer (score 0):

Solve Problem using below code

```
@Override
 public void onAttachedToWindow() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onAttachedToWindow();  

     handler.postDelayed(mUpdateUiMsg, 100);
    //this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);     
 }


 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
   return true;
  }
  if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
   return true;
  }

  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }


 private Runnable mUpdateUiMsg = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);


         }
    };
```

Comment: You cannot get full screen with this.

Answer (score 0):

Solve Problem using below code

```
@Override
 public void onAttachedToWindow() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onAttachedToWindow();  

     handler.postDelayed(mUpdateUiMsg, 100);
    //this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);     
 }


 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
   return true;
  }
  if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
   return true;
  }

  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }


 private Runnable mUpdateUiMsg = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);


         }
    };
```

In my case,after overridding onAttachedToWindow(),i found `overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim)` or

```
<style name="Theme.NoTitleBar.WithColoredSpinners" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AnimationActivity</item>
</style>
```

Did not work, but problem was solved using these code, but I don't know why yet.
And the same, I don't know the method `onAttachedToWindow()` what to do and how it effects?