# Android full screen not working whenever a service is launched

Tags: android

For an application in kindle fire I want to make the screen free of soft keys.

For that I update my manifest as

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    myLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgfinal);

    createMainView();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

    super.onAttachedToWindow(); 
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return false;
}

public void createMainView()
{
    LinearLayout HomePage = new LinearLayout(this);

    HomePage.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    HomePage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    myLayout.addView(HomePage);
    TextView name = new TextView(this); 

    name.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    name.setMinHeight(46);
    HomePage.addView(name);
    LinearLayout HomePageHorLayOut = new LinearLayout(this);
    HomePageHorLayOut.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    HomePageHorLayOut.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    HomePage.addView(HomePageHorLayOut);

    TextView name1 = new TextView(this);    

    name1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    name1.setText("     ");
    name1.setWidth(274);
    HomePageHorLayOut.addView(name1);

    final Button PIBtn=new Button(this);
    PIBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pilatest);
    PIBtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    HomePageHorLayOut.addView(PIBtn); 
    PIBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
        }
    });
}
```

In this case whenever the application is launched the screen hasn't any softkeys, but whenever the button is pressed the kindle fire will bring the user to the time settings frame and the softkeys will not be hidden even if we get back to the application.

I found that, almost same issue has [already been reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823529/android-full-screen-not-working-when-activity-is-launched-by-a-service), but I've tried that answer but the result was the same.

Is there any option to hide the softkeys while get back to main application from settings?